# java syntax statement beginning with dot

Tags: java

I haven't programmed in Java for a while and I ran into this code on the Apache Kafka tutorials. I don't understand what the dots in the beginning of the statements do. Does this mean create a new variable 'wordCounts' of type KTable, assign textLines, and then call wordCounts.flatMapValues(), wordCounts.map(), and then wordCounts.countByKey()? I see this notation in Javascript as well but I don't know what it's called.:

```
   KTable wordCounts = textLines
    // Split each text line, by whitespace, into words.
    .flatMapValues(value -> Arrays.asList(value.toLowerCase().split("\\W+")))

    // Ensure the words are available as record keys for the next aggregate operation.
    .map((key, value) -> new KeyValue<>(value, value))

    // Count the occurrences of each word (record key) and store the results into a table named "Counts".
    .countByKey("Counts")
```

Comment: Line breaks aren't significant in Java. Imagine all the comments and line breaks weren't there.

Comment: They are just separating them for clarity. It's interpreted as `textLines.flatMapValues(...).map(...).countByKey(...)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The statement begins with `textLines` and then continues on the next line, but the method [`flatMapValues`](https://kafka.apache.org/0100/javadoc/org/apache/kafka/streams/kstream/KStream.html#flatMapValues(org.apache.kafka.streams.kstream.ValueMapper)) is being invoked on `textLines`. That is then `map`ed and counted. This style is sometimes referred to as a [fluent interface](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fluent_interface).

Comment: Doh. Thank you. I didn't catch the semi colon way at the end and think of removing all the spaces. It's obvious now.

Answer (score 2):

This:

```
KTable wordCounts = textLines
// Split each text line, by whitespace, into words.
.flatMapValues(value -> Arrays.asList(value.toLowerCase().split("\\W+")))
```

Is effectively the same as this:

```
KTable wordCounts = textLines.flatMapValues(value -> Arrays.asList(value.toLowerCase().split("\\W+")))
```

The whitespace and comments don't really matter to the compiler, the "dot" is simply dereferencing the last symbol, which was the variable `textLines`.

Answer (score 0):

**They are just calling the flatMapValues method which is associates with textLines**
.flatMapValues is not in starting line, they had just entered to keep it in new line for better clarification of the code, There is no concept to start method with **.**(dot) in the starting in JAVA or also in any language

Comment: "Java" doesn't stand for everything, so it's not in ALL CAPS. It's just a name.